# Use of "in" vs. "with"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, parallelism

If one has an *interest **in** something* and a *fascination **with** something* which one of the next is correct?

> I've always had an interest and fascination **in** something

or

> I've always had an interest and fascination **with** something

Comment: Not a daft question, as English sometimes has rules (or perhaps they'd be better called conventions) as to which other 'rule' to break when it's almost impossible (or very inconvenient) not to. However, here, the rule is put in the different prepositions: John always had an interest in - bordering on a fascination with - knitting turtle-neck jumpers. Peter looked at and then voted against the plans.

Comment: I approve of and voted for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idiomatically, it's almost always [an interest **in**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22have+always+had+an+interest+in%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (18500 hits in Google Books, compared to just 7 for [an interest **with**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22have%20always%20had%20an%20interest%20in%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22have%20always%20had%20an%20interest%20with%22&oq=%22have%20always%20had%20an%20interest%20with%22&gs_l=serp.3...3567.6149.0.6646.7.7.0.0.0.0.81.366.7.7.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.pLYdf19m-9s&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44342787,d.d2k&fp=58e13a8353fb6902&biw=1501&bih=937)). But it's [a fascination **with**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22had%20a%20fascination%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22have%20always%20had%20a%20fascination%20with%22&oq=%22have%20always%20had%20a%20fascination%20with%22&gs_l=serp.3...9179.10443.2.10942.5.5.0.0.0.0.280.440.4j0j1.5.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.CbRz2sWocZY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44342787,d.d2k&fp=58e13a8353fb6902&biw=1501&bih=937) (2680 hits), rather than [a fascination **in**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22had%20a%20fascination%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22have%20always%20had%20a%20fascination%20in%22&oq=%22have%20always%20had%20a%20fascination%20in%22&gs_l=serp.3...3842.5126.3.5371.6.6.0.0.0.0.58.278.6.6.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.-R2yliglP_s&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44342787,d.d2k&fp=58e13a8353fb6902&biw=1501&bih=937) (3 hits).

OP's usage is thus never going to sound quite right, because he's trying to force a single preposition to fit two mutually incompatible contexts. Strictly speaking, it should be...

> I've always had an **interest in**, and **fascination with**, something.

But actually we often avoid that complexity by just letting the preposition agree with the *final* context, so in principle OP's usage should be okay using **with**. The problem here is that in practice, to *have a fascination **with** something* is nowhere near as common as to *have an interest **in** it*, so using *with* to cover both contexts still doesn't sound too good.

Therefore I think the best solution is to swap the contexts around...

> I've always had a **fascination and interest in** something.

Answer (score 1):

I've always had an interest, and fascination, in something.

I find that focuses the attention on interest, making the answer fairly straightforward. Of course, you could switch the order, as long as you switch the corresponding parts too.

Comment: Yes, but if I use it without the commas ? Is it _in_ or _with_ ?

Comment: ............No.